# Basic calculation like count average in chromadb from an datafram

Tags: dataframe, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb, openaiembeddings

I have an Dataframe and I integrated with chromadb with openai embedding but am not able to get any response for integer datatype column as well as am not able to get response like the employee who have greater than 3 siblings these king of query am not getting proper response is it possible chromadb will able to answer this query.

```
titanic_data = pd.read_csv("/content/titanic.csv")
MAX_PASSENGERS = 1000  # Maximum number of passengers to analyze
NAME_COLUMN = "name"
SURVIVAL_COLUMN = "survived"
Sibsp_COLUMN= "sibsp"
ubset_titanic = titanic_data.head(MAX_PASSENGERS)
from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
df_loader = DataFrameLoader(subset_titanic, page_content_column=NAME_COLUMN)
df_document = df_loader.load()
display(df_document)
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=250, chunk_overlap=10)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(df_document)
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key='TOKEN'))

query = "person who have more than 3 sibilings in the disaster "
docs = db.similarity_search(query)
print(docs\[0\].page_content)
```

OUTPUT:Danbom, Master. Gilbert Sigvard Emanuel   but there are many people who have more than 3 siblings  I want output gicing the number os person or giving all their names  cn any one provide me with the solution for it using chromadb and openai embeddings

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
record_cnt = 10 #you can specify based on your requirement 
docs = db.similarity_search(query, k= record_cnt)
```

Comment: No basically i want to perform statistical calculation in vectordb is there any way to achieve that . Similarity search works on cosine similarity which breaks the content into chunks and perform similarity vector search and retrieve data but it not able to perform calculation using intergers like summ, avg,count and etc.. is there any other way to achieve statistic calculation in vector db.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform any statistical or analytical calculation using similarity_search function in chromaDB. As the name tells it only looks for closest data points for a question in vector db.

ChromaDB is not a natural language understanding (NLU) system. It retrieves data points from the vector store based on their similarity to the query, but it doesn't inherently understand the context provided by the user. Go thorough the [documentation](https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide) might be helpful.

To enhance contextual understanding, you typically use ChromaDB in combination with other NLU models or LLMs, like integrating with [langchain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/chat_vector_db).